# flutter:: Is it possible to get string from another file in stateful?

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful

How to get data from previous page when using stateful String link.
Is it possible to get string from another file in stateful?
I need to get the string from another file b into the stateful of file a. In case of stateless this was possible, but in stateful it is not possible.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to disagree but using global variables in this situation when you can fix your problem easily is not wise although it works and it is very easy.

if you want to send data to another page via pushing a new page you can always use that newPage Constructor

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BalancePage(
                    items: "item",
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

New Page

```
 class BalancePage extends StatefulWidget {
   String? items;

   BalancePage({
     this.items,
   });

   @override
   _BalancePageState createState() => _BalancePageState();
}
```

if you want to take data from another class you can set a getter

```
class newVal(){
  String val ="ss";
  
  String getVal(){
    return val;
  }

}
```

and you can call it anywhere like this

```
   String ss = newVal().getVal;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Why do you deprecate using global variables? Are there any downsides?

Comment: @lele there are many downsides to that, for example, it can create memory issues. 
it is not bad to use it sometimes but for a thing like this ... no.

Comment: So, is there any way to get a string without using a global variable?

Comment: @lele yes the second way I mentioned is usable in any case